Sponsoring a Sefer - R' Yitzchak Meir Morgenstern Shlit"a
BS"D
Does anyone know someone who either has connections with publishers or wants to support publishing a sefer?  I also want to help print a sefer, preferably in the realm of chassidus or halacha. Specifically I want to find a way to publish the seforim of R' Yitzchak Meir Morgenstern Shlit"a. I appreciate if anyone has any connections.
Thank you.

"specifically i want to find a way to support the seforim of R' Yitzchak Meir Morgenstern Shlit"a so if anyone has any connections would be appreciated" Have you tried reaching out to his yeshivah? http://torahindex.com/EN/Inst/institutionsDetail.aspx?index=1&instID=6161

Dayan Raskin is raising money to print his newly expanded commentary on the siddur: https://www.kehot.org/Dedicate/Products/HP-SRH

Reach out to https://x.com/SeforimChatter

You can also reach out to Sea of Wisdom, they put out the teachings of Rav Morgenstern in English, and just put out a beautiful book on challenges in English from Rav Morgenstern's teachings.
info@seaofwisdom.org
3052091068

Here is the information of Rabbi Morgenstern' organization that publishes his Seforim currently. This is from the first pages of the one of his Seforim. I am positive they'll be happy to hear about your offer

הוצאת ”מכון ים החכמה”
שע”י ישיבת ”תורת חכם” ללימוד הנגלה והנסתר
ירושלים עיה”ק תובב”א
ת.ד. 5245 ירושלים
טלפקס: 02-5289583 נייד: 057-3153884
דוא”ל tc7@bezeqint.net

